# how do I format date when using pikaday

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pikaday

I am using pikaday module for datepicker, but the format comes as inappropriate format. I tried adding this line of code but still not working:

```
.config(['pikadayConfigProvider', function (pikaday) {
    pikaday.setConfig({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        format: "YYYY/MM/DD"
    });
}])
```

This is how my html looks like:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" pikaday="myPickerObject" name="time" ng-model="clas.class_.time" placeholder="Enter time" tabindex="3">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also tried to add as an inline attribute

> format = "yyyy/mm/dd"

still not working.

Any help

Comment: https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

Comment: @Rayon i have looked at this link but still I am not able to fix this... Could you tell me more specifically what should I add or modify

Comment: Do share a fiddle so that one can play with it....

Comment: also I would be more happy if I would find a datetimepicker not only datepicker, are there any datetimepicker for angularjs 1.2.16, ui-bootstrap 0.12.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use moment.js and set the format by setting

```
defaultDate : moment().format("MMM YYYY")
```

this will be the initial input date display format. 
For displaying/processing the date in other desired formats, use

```
var field = document.getElementById('datepicker');
var picker = new Pikaday({
onSelect: function(date) {
    field.value = this.getMoment().format('Do MMMM YYYY');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use moment.js to set the date format:

```
var picker = new Pikaday(
{
    field: document.getElementById('eDate'),
    toString(date, format) { // using moment
        return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

quick update, if you don't want to use moment.js, you can fdo the following

```
new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('eDate'), 
    toString: function(date) {
        var parts = [('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2), ('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2), date.getFullYear()];
        return parts.join("-");
    }
})
```

this will produce 18-07-1980. You can change from '-' to '/' by changing return parts.join("-"); and you can rearrange parts to apply mm/dd/yyyy via parts array